# Fires query to return a single child and update a value

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function that queries Firebase using .queryEqual to get me th node I want to update but I do not know how to set the value to false. Here is the function I have:

```
func addrShipDefault() {
    let ref = Router.addrShip.reference().child(self.userId)
    let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "isDefault").queryEqual(toValue: true)
    query.setValue(false, "isDefault")
}
```

Would someone be able to tell me how to query Firebase for the node I am looking for and update its value?

I have done other updates using ref.updateChildValues, but for those I know the exact path.  This time I need to lookup the node that has isDefault set to true and modify it.

Hope this makes sense!!

Thank you for the help

**** UPDATE TO SHOW DB STRUCTURE

```
{
  "addr_01" : {
    "address1" : "63 Park Ave",
    "address2" : "Unit #2",
    "city" : "Greenland",
    "firstName" : "John",
    "id" : "addr_01",
    "isDefault" : true,
    "lastName" : "Smith",
    "state" : "MA",
    "zipcode" : "01890"
  },
  "addr_02" : {
    "address1" : "101 Lafayette Rd",
    "address2" : "",
    "city" : "Rye",
    "firstName" : "Say It In 3D",
    "id" : "addr_02",
    "isDefault" : false,
    "lastName" : "",
    "state" : "NH",
    "zipcode" : "03870"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the structure of your firebase db?

Comment: I have added an update to the post showing the structure of that node.  Thanks for the quick reply!!

Comment: have you tried this: `query.setValue(["isDefault": false])` instead of `query.setValue(false, "isDefault")` because I think `setValue` accepts a dictionary.

Comment: No, the compiler will not accept that, there is no match. The syntax is .setValue(Any, String), that is the only match

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)

> you can  update a child
>   without rewriting the entire object. If you want to allow users to
>   update their profiles you could update the username as follows:

```
self.ref.child("users/(user.uid)/username").setValue(username)
```

Now using the above example in your case:

We can do something like this: (I havent tried it but I think you can get the idea)

```
let ref = Router.addrShip.reference().child(self.userId)
let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "isDefault").queryEqual(toValue: true)

//query.child("isDefault").setValue(false)

//Updated Code

query.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) { (snapshot) in
          let newRef = snapshot.ref.child("isDefault")
          newRef.setValue(false, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
                   print("SetValue")
          })
}
```

Note that from official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference)

Function signature for `setValue` method is as follows:

```
func setValue(_ value: Any?)
```

As can be seen above, it accepts optional of any type value, which means you can pass any value for valid json.

Also note that there is also a method with completion block

```
func setValue(_ value: Any?, withCompletionBlock block: @escaping (Error?, DatabaseReference) -> Void)
```

Comment: Hmmm, I tried this and I get this compiler error:  Value of type 'DatabaseQuery' has no member 'child'

Comment: @LilMoke yes you are right, I have made changes in the answer, please take a look and give your feedback, thanks